# How to change Cups printing options

Tags: c++, linux, cups

Is there a way to set the default printing options like page size, resolution, color ... for a given printer using the CUPS API or any other API (PPD, HTTP & IPP)?
An example could really help.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are looking for following functions from CUPS API

1. `cupsAddOptions`
2. `cupsAddDest`
3. `cupsSetDests/cupsSaveDest`

The official [documentation](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/api-cups.html) is quite well documented with examples.

There is also a related [book](https://www.cups.org/book.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you maybe provide an example for coloring ? I already tried printing to Gray Scale using "cupsAddOption("saturation", "0", num, *options)" but it didn't work ! Also I can't seem to find a list of supported options by the printer like media for paer size and resolution ...! What's the one for coloring called ?

Comment: just do it from command line tool `lpoptions`, then open the config file get the option names accordingly.

Comment: That's what I'am doing so far, but for my application I need a generic way that will work with any printer. For Page Size and Resolution It doesn't seem to be a problem, as it's the same name for all. but for coloring and GrayScale it's different each time !

Comment: Some options are vendor specific so you cannot hardcode an options name, so I think the best way is to get the list of printer specific settings first, `lpoptions -l` does it, then figure out in which option you are interested in. You can check the source codes of `lpoptions` tool to figure out how it lists printer supported options

Comment: The link throws a page has moved error.